# How do I disable an element after it's clicked in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 elements that are bound to a click function inside a directive using Angular.

The problem I'm having is when one of those elements are are clicked very quickly, the other element would fire. 
You can see an example here: http://430designs.com/xperience/black-label-app/deck.php

If you click the "X" several times, rapidly, you'll see the heart glow instead of the "X". You may have to do it a few times to actually see it happen, but it will happen.

I need to disable the heart/dislike buttons after the click and then reenable them when the function is finished.

Here's my controller code. The directive for the "fake swipe" starts on line 87:

```
angular.module('black-label', ['ngTouch', 'ngSwippy'])
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $timeout, $window) {
    $scope.cardsCollection = [{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_01.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_02.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_03.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_04.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_05.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/thor_06.jpg',collection:'thoroughbred',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_01.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_02.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_03.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_04.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_05.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/rhap_06.jpg',collection:'rhapsody',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_01.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_02.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_03.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_04.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_05.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cha_06.jpg',collection:'chalet',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_01.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_02.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_03.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_04.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_05.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/mod_06.jpg',collection:'modern',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_01.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_02.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_03.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_04.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_05.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/ind_06.jpg',collection:'indulgence',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_01.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_02.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_03.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_04.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_05.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/cnt_06.jpg',collection:'center-stage',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_01.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_02.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_03.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_04.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_05.jpg',collection:'vineyard',},{thumbnail:'images/deck/vin_06.jpg',collection:'vineyard',}];
    // Do the shuffle
    var shuffleArray = function(array) {
        var m = array.length,
            t, i;
        // While there remain elements to shuffle
        while (m) {
            // Pick a remaining element
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
            // And swap it with the current element.
            t = array[m];
            array[m] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
        return array;
    };
    $scope.deck = shuffleArray($scope.cardsCollection);
    $scope.myCustomFunction = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.clickedTimes = $scope.clickedTimes + 1;
            $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Click on item' });
        });
    }; //end myCustomFunction
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.showinfo = false;
    $scope.clickedTimes = 0;
    $scope.actions = [];
    $scope.picks = [];
    var counterRight = 0;
    var counterLeft = 0;
    var newVar = $scope;

    $scope.swipeend = function() {
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Collection Empty' });
        $window.location.href = 'theme-default.php';
    }; //endswipeend
    $scope.swipeLeft = function(person) {
        //Essentially do nothing
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Left swipe' });
        $('.circle.x').addClass('dislike');
        $('.circle.x').removeClass('dislike');
        $(this).each(function() {
            return counterLeft++;
        });
    }; //end swipeLeft
    $scope.swipeRight = function(person) {
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Right swipe' });
        // Count the number of right swipes
        $(this).each(function() {
            return counterRight++;
        });
        $scope.picks.push(person.collection);
        // Checking the circles
        $('.circle').each(function() {
          if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
              $(this).addClass('checked');
              return false;
          }
        });

        if (counterRight === 4) {
            // Calculate and store the frequency of each swipe
            var frequency = $scope.picks.reduce(function(frequency, swipe) {
                var sofar = frequency[swipe];
                if (!sofar) {
                    frequency[swipe] = 1;
                } else {
                    frequency[swipe] = frequency[swipe] + 1;
                }
                return frequency;
            }, {});
            Object.keys(frequency).forEach(function(element) {
              console.log('Person ', element,': ', frequency[element]);
            });
            var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(frequency).map(function(k){ return frequency[k]; })); // most frequent
            // find key for the most frequent value
            var winner = Object.keys(frequency).find(function(element){return frequency[element] == max; });
            //Underscore
            // var winner = _.findKey(frequency, val => val === max); 
            $window.location.href = 'theme-' + winner + '.php';
        } //end 4 swipes
    }; //end swipeRight

})
.directive('ngSwippy', ['swipe', function(swipe) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            $(".fake-swipe").on("click", function(evt) {

                var sign        = $(this).hasClass("swippy-like")?1:-1;
                var card        = $("div.content-wrapper.swipable-card:last", element/*"div.ng-swippy"*/);

                $(this).addClass('happy');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    card.trigger("mousemove");
                },300);
                $(this).removeClass('happy');

                card.trigger("mousedown");
                card.animate({ left:sign*$("body").width() }, 350, function() {
                  card.trigger("mouseup");
                });

                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @LodewijkBogaards solution, you can also have a variable in the controller, which is `true` while the click listener is running. To implement such a behavior you simply add a variable to the controller (e.g. `var isRunning = false;`). You then need to add a condition to the click listener function:

```
var isRunning = false;
function click() {
    if(!isRunning) {
        isRunning = true;

        [...your code...]

        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

This will also work on elements like a `<div/>` or an `<a/>`, whereas the solution of adding `ng-disabled` will only work on buttons.

Comment: @ssc-herp3 I tried this, however it didn't work. If I click at a normal rate, everything is fine. But if I click really fast it still simulates a right swipe sometimes. I'm thinking there's an issue with waiting for the first click event to complete before firing it again. How can I make it fire only once per second? Or add a loader of some sort?

Comment: The `if`-condition prevents this behavior. The click listener can be executed simultaneously, but the condition stops your actual code. Firing only once a second would be an unpleasant hack (but easily achievable with using `setTimeout()`).

Comment: That's kind of what I did. Thanks for the help @ssc-hrep3. I ended up toggling an absolute positioned div for 1 second after the click. I DID NOT want to do this and I understand this is extremely hackish. However, I just couldn't get it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The general principle is this: The first thing you do when you handle the click event is set some boolean to true, e.g. `$scope.actionInProgress = true`. On your button you should have the attribute `ng-disabled="!actionInProgress"`. Then when you action completes you simply set `$scope.actionInProgress = false`.

People answering questions on StackOverflow generally don't like doing your work in your codebase. People like answering questions that are reduced to the heart of the problem. I am also one of those people and I am quite certain from the looks of your code you are quite capable of making such a change slight change yourself.

Good luck!

Comment: This, however, won't work, if the element is not a `<button>` or an `<input type="submit">`. In his example link, the element is a `<div>`

Comment: Then simply only do your work `if ($scope.actionInProgress)`

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards, thank you for the tip. I will do that next time. I did try the example, however it seems that it still does it. Is there something I'm missing? I'm using the [ng-swippy](https://github.com/B1naryStudio/ng-swippy) library. I'm trying to simulate the swipe by triggering the mouse down/up/move actions. Does that help at all?